Como adicionar tarefas para um usuário específico como administrador em uma aplicação Python com Firebase?
Fiz uma pequena aplicação desktop em python que usa Firebase como banco de dados. Na aplicação você cadastra seu usuário e insere tarefas (como um trello).
Além disso, existe um login Administrador, no qual o administrador pode inserir tarefas para os outros usuários cadastrados, que ele seleciona.
Abaixo está a função do administrador para gerenciar um usuário e adicionar uma tarefa deste usuário
def gerenciar_usuario(user_id):
    global frame_tarefas_usuario_interior, canvas_usuario, canvas
    
    # Obtendo os dados do usuário pelo user_id
    doc = db.collection('usuarios').document(user_id).get()
    user_data = doc.to_dict()
    
    # Verificando se o usuário existe
    if not user_data:
        print("Usuário não encontrado")
        return
    
    username = user_data['username'] # Se precisar exibir o nome do usuário, mas usar o user_id para associações

    def adicionar_tarefa_usuario():
        tarefa = entrada_tarefa_usuario.get("1.0", ctk.END).strip()
        if tarefa:
            try:
                print(f"Adicionando tarefa para o usuário: {user_id}")  # Use o user_id
                db.collection('tarefas').add({
                    'tarefa': tarefa,
                    'user_id': user_id,  # Salve o user_id ao invés de username
                    'data_check': None,
                    'alta_prioridade': False,
                    'timestamp': firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP
                })
                entrada_tarefa_usuario.delete("1.0", ctk.END)
                atualizar_lista_tarefas_usuario()
            except GoogleAPICallError as e:
                messagebox.showerror("Erro", f"Erro ao adicionar tarefa: {e}")
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning("Aviso", "A tarefa não pode estar vazia.")

Porém, ao inserir tarefas para um usuário selecionado, todos os outros recebem a mesma tarefa, o que não deveria acontecer. Apenas o usuário selecionado pelo administrador deveria receber a tarefa.
Essa é a função pós inserção de uma tarefa. Onde a tarefa é fixada na aplicação junto aos botões de dar "Check", "Editar" e "Excluir" a tarefa. Ela fica armazenada db.collection, que está definida com user_id.
def atualizar_lista_tarefas_usuario():
        global canvas_usuario, canvas

        for widget in frame_tarefas_usuario_interior.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()

        tarefas_ref = db.collection('tarefas').where('user_id', '==', user_id).order_by('alta_prioridade', direction=firestore.Query.DESCENDING).order_by('timestamp', direction=firestore.Query.DESCENDING).stream()    

        for doc in tarefas_ref:
            tarefa_data = doc.to_dict() 
            # restante do código...

Eu acredito que o problema seja no uso do user_id no lugar do username, mas não tenho certeza.
Eu gostaria de saber se alguém que entende de python poderia me ajudar a evitar esse problema, tentei refazer o código várias vezes, mas não consigo fazer com que a aplicação defina uma tarefa para o usuário selecionado username, como consta no Firebase. Qualquer dúvida, é só falarem,

Boas-vindas. Essa pergunta já foi feita, e as devidas orientações foram fornecidas via comentário. Se precisar comentar ou revisar a dúvida, para a comunidade conseguir lhe ajudar, faça na pergunta original.
